# 400 - Bad Request","message":"missing 'boundary' param for multipart file upload"

Tags: python, api

RESULT:

```py
{"httpStatus":"400 - Bad Request","message":"missing 'boundary' param for multipart file upload","requestId":"37af4429-4259-40e4-9549-71dcb05c00d3","transactionId":"1d91ca0e-d374-402f-a307-705fd40220d4"}}
```

Below is the code for the same:

I am trying to run this API call but I am unable to figure out the boundary issue:

```py
dir_name = '/Users/***/Downloads/***'
os.chdir(dir_name)

pattern='***_*.csv'

for x in glob.glob(pattern):
    file_name=os.path.join(dir_name,x)
    print (file_name)
    
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("***.***.***.com")
dataList = []
boundary = 'wL36Yn8afVp8Ag7AmP8qZ0SA4n1v9T'
dataList.append('--' + boundary)
dataList.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Content-Disposition;')

dataList.append('Content-Type: {}'.format('multipart/form-data'))
dataList.append('')

dataList.append("form-data")
dataList.append('--' + boundary)
dataList.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Content-Type;')

dataList.append('Content-Type: {}'.format('multipart/form-data'))
dataList.append('')

dataList.append("text/plain")
dataList.append('--' + boundary)
dataList.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=name;')

dataList.append('Content-Type: {}'.format('multipart/form-data'))
dataList.append('')

dataList.append("file")
dataList.append('--' + boundary)
dataList.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename={0}'.format(file_name))

fileType = mimetypes.guess_type('/C:/Users/TEST/Desktop/***/TEST/***.csv')[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
dataList.append('Content-Type: {}'.format(fileType))
dataList.append('')

with open(file_name) as f:
  dataList.append(f.read())
dataList.append('--'+boundary+'--')
dataList.append('')
body = '\r\n'.join(dataList)
payload = body
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'X-API-TOKEN': '***',
  'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary={}'.format(boundary)
}
```

Comment: remove the content-type headers

Comment: You missed code which perform request.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I didn't get you. This code was generated from postman itself wherein I have updated just the file name piece